# System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The handle is invalid

Tags: python, powershell, jenkins, cmake, continuous-integration

I am facing the below specified issue when build triggered in Jenkins(pipeline project). But no issue occurred when i run from PowerShell prompt.

We have run the job in slave (remote) machine. In that remote machine, the build is run properly. When I automate in the Jenkins I have facing the below failure.

```
    Executing task: build
    Executing: ../venv/Scripts/python.exe utils.py src ../cireports
    Executing: jshint             --reporter=checkstyle ../src/poststudio             >../cireports/JsHintAnalysis.xml
    An error occurred when executing task 'build'.  
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
   at Cake.Powershell.CakePSHostRawUserInterface.get_BufferSize()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand.InstantiateLineOutputInterface()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand.BeginProcessing()
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   at Cake.Powershell.PowershellRunner.Invoke(String script, PowershellSettings settings)
   at Submission#0.StartPowershellScript(String script)
   at Submission#0.<.ctor>b__6()
   at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Does>b__0(ICakeContext context)
   at Cake.Core.ActionTask.Execute(ICakeContext context)
   at Cake.Core.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(CakeTask task, ICakeContext context)
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTask(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report)
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.RunTarget(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, String target)
   at Cake.Scripting.BuildScriptHost.RunTarget(String target)
   at Submission#0..ctor(Session session, Object& submissionResult)
   at Submission#0.<Factory>(Session session)
   at Roslyn.Scripting.CommonScriptEngine.Execute[T](String code, String path, DiagnosticBag diagnostics, Session session, Boolean isInteractive)
   at Roslyn.Scripting.Session.Execute(String code)
   at Cake.Scripting.Roslyn.Stable.DefaultRoslynScriptSession.Execute(Script script)
   at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptRunner.Run(IScriptHost host, FilePath scriptPath, IDictionary`2 arguments)
   at Cake.Commands.BuildCommand.Execute(CakeOptions options)
   at Cake.CakeApplication.Run(CakeOptions options)
   at Cake.Program.Main()
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // gitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILUR
```

Comment: Try adding python to your tags for more exposure

Comment: what do you mean by "when I automated in Jenkins"? can you please detail the steps that you do?